# Android webview keep previous page content without reload?

Tags: android, webview, xamarin.android

The webview seems like only keep previous page's url and scroll position, not keep the content? I have a main page with json data, and a child page. The main page generate hyperlink form some json data to open child page in a new window. In laptop browser, I just have to close the child page in new window. But in webview, while I press back button, it can go back the main page, but it reload again and not keep the previous content. How can I make the webview go back without reload?

```
main.html with dynamic content
<a href='child.html' target=target="_blank"......
press back button, success go back, but the main page reload and lost dynamic content
```

my code as bellow:

```
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
webView.Settings.DatabaseEnabled=true;
webView.Settings.DatabasePath = AppConfig.Path;

webView.SetWebViewClient(new HybridWebViewClient());


public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    if (webView != null && webView.CanGoBack())
    {
        webView.GoBack();
        GoBackFlag = true;
    }
    else {
        base.OnBackPressed();
    }
}

public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
{
    if (GoBackFlag)
    {
        GoBackFlag = true;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        view.LoadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
}

public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
{
    if (GoBackFlag)
    {
        GoBackFlag = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

Thanks~

Answer (score 3):

One thing to remember is that a WebView is not a full internet browser. It is a View that is designed specifically to load web content. If you have a single WebView and are switching out content (including going back) it will have to reload the content every time.

Look into using different fragments with WebViews embedded in them. That way when you load the content it should stay loaded (or cached). Then you can perform all of your navigation between the WebView fragments.

You could also have multiple WebViews in one Activity and set the visibility flag to GONE or VISIBLE depending on what should be shown on screen.

Comment: That's a pity. I will do some alternative plan, thank you ~~

Comment: @Renkuei, What approach did you go with?

Comment: @ToolFan sorry for late reply. It seems that i use another webview to achieve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed by opening new webview in new activity. Depending upon the need, the new webview can be:

- opened in New instance of same activity. Make sure -->
  android:launchMode="standard"
- opened in New instance of different activity.